# Generate Select List for Each Group of Records with the Same Value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am using the array below to echo a HTML select box but I haven't been able to figure out how to do the loop using the unique values:

```
sid     evid
13      1
14      1
15      2
16      3
```

I am trying to loop through the above array by the unique values stored in 'evid' so I can create a select box which groups by 'evid'.  At the moment, my loop produces 4 select boxes when it should only produce 3.  sid 13 and 14 is outputting a select box each since my code isn't grouping them but I just can't get my head around how I get these two values to group during the loop.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Code I'm using:

```
<?php while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($sessions)){ ?>
<?php foreach ($evs as $ev){ 
        if ($ev['evid'] == $s['evid']){     
?>

    <form action="" method="">
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label></label>
                    <select name="sessions[]">
                        <option name="sessions[]" value="<?php echo $s['sid']; ?>"><?php echo $s['sname']; ?></option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php } // end if match ?>

    <?php } // end foreach ?>

<?php } // end while ?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? If it is coming from a database, you might want to consider refining your query to use a `distinct` or `group by` clause rather than doing it in a loop, which will probably be less efficient.

Comment: Data is from a MySQL DB. The data that I am getting is what I want and need - I just need to be able to tell PHP to loop by unique 'evid'

Comment: Please consider re-wording your question.  Your question title says "only unique" yet you are invalidating answers that suggest `array_unique()` because you want to keep duplicates.  This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AJ - the title says unique array 'values'. If you think there's a more helpful title then please do suggest

Comment: How about "Generate Select List for Each Group of Records with the Same Value"?  Not sure if that's what you want, because it's not clear to me (and others) **what you want**.  Try to focus on your desired outcome, not the logic to get you there, when choosing a title and forming the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you need, and assuming the arrays are sorted, have a try with:

```
$sid  = array(13, 14, 15, 16);
$evid = array(1, 1, 2, 3);

$current_evid = $evid[0];
echo "<select .....>\n";
for ($i=0; $i<count($evid); $i++) {
    if ($current_evid != $evid[$i]) {
        echo "</select>\n";
        echo "<select ...>\n";
        $current_evid = $evid[$i];
    }
    echo "<option value=".$sid[$i].".....\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
```

**output:**

```
<select .....>
<option value=13.....
<option value=14.....
</select>
<select ...>
<option value=15.....
</select>
<select ...>
<option value=16.....
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP's `array_unique` - details here:  http://php.net/function.array-unique

Or - if you're using something like MySQL to get the data, try using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` statement.

---

**EDIT per comment:**

If you want/need to keep your original array, just copy the array, and use `array_unique` on the copy.  Then, use the copy to create the select dropdown.

**Alternate solutoin:**

Keep a `$values_written` array.

In your loop, before you write the `<option>`, check that it's value is not already in the `$values_written` (using PHP's `in_array` - [details here](http://php.net/function.in-array))

Then write the `<option>`.

Then add it's value to the array (using PHP's `array_push` - [details here](http://php.net/function.array-push))

Comment: I think array_unique removes the duplicate values - I still want to retain the key->value but I just want it to know that the value is the same and group them together.

Comment: @chocolatecoco - right, but if you just set a new variable to the array_unique... like $arrayCopy = $myArray;  array_unique($arrayCopy) - then use $arrayCopy for the loop.

Comment: @chocolatecoco - added another solution to try - I believe either will work.

Comment: @Dave - sorry, just not getting this. I've updated original question with the code I am currently using - are you able to suggest how I modify this code to work?

Comment: @chocolatecoco - sorry - I believe I've more than answered your question and even included links on each element you'd need to use - time to move on and hope that you'll spend a few minutes trying to learn about the PHP items mentioned / available to you.  Wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Feed your array into [array_unique()](http://php.net/function.array-unique)

Comment: I want the duplicate values so this function won't work for me. I  need to be able to tell PHP to loop by unique 'evid' but retain the 'sid'